# Issue with updating phpMyAdmin - Server 2012 - IIS

Tags: phpmyadmin, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm experiencing a error HTTP500 when updating phpMyAdmin on my Server 2012R2 - IIS Server.

I followed the process below:

1. Downloaded latest version of phpMyAdmin 4.7.6 (current version is 4.0.10.7)
2. Removed all files from inetpub\wwwroot\phpMyAdmin
3. Copied all files from 4.7.6 to phpMyAdmin Folder

   Tried to navigate to localhost/phpMyAdmin - got a error 500

   Tried to copy config.sample.inc.php from 4.0.10.7 folder to the inetpub\wwwroot\phpMyAdmin same error 500.

Everywhere I looked this seems to be the process to update. Am I doing something wrong here?

Edit: Updated PHP to V7.2 - still unable to access phpMyAdmin 
Edit2: Updated MySQL to v 5.7.20 no dice.

Answer (score 0):

OK figured it out. 
installed PHP 7.2 
installed PHP Manager IIS 
Changed PHP to 7.2 registered version 
updated phpmyadmin - error because MYSQL5.1 not compatible with 4.7.6 
installed MYSQL 5.5 
was able to access phpmyadmin without any issues